# How to trigger a function on a certain time using timestamps from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

Let's say i am storing some timestamps in my MongoDB, each timestamp indicates a time when some certain function should be run.

I am not sure what should be the correct approach to this since I am new in backend developing.

Mongo data structure goes like this(this is just an example):

```
{id: 115155, userId: 152115, timestamp: 13-09-2019:15:30:00}
```

and on this certain time I want to trigger a function:

```
someFunction(eventId, userId){ ...something here }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the format of timestamp you get from mongodb into something like this - "13 Sept 2019 18:39:40" or "2019-01-01 00:00:00". Then you need to parse the timestamp you get from mongodb using this Date.parse()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Once that is done you need to get difference between *timestamp* and *current time* and use that difference in a setTimeout() function, which takes 2 parameters - *function to be run* and *time in milliseconds*

```
    let timediff = new Date() - Date.parse("2019-09-13 18:54:50");

    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log("Called when current time = mongodb timestamp"); 
    }, timediff);
```

Comment: I know that the time format is wrong, it was just an example, and I cant write a function like this for every timestamp im storing, there are hundreds of them..

Comment: You don't have to rewrite the function, you could have a separate module to handle this.